# What is the `__identify__` route that Capybara looks for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

When I disable Webmock or VCR I get the following error in my Rspec tests. Apparently it's looking for an `/__identify__` route.

```
          WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
        Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://127.0.0.1:51768/__identify__ with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}
```

A bit of googling shows that this is something specific to Capybara, but I wasn't able to find out what exactly it's trying to do and why it might need to be stubbed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be stubbing it - you should be allowing it (like all requests to your app).  Its a route added via middleware Capybara installs when it starts up the "server" thread running your app. Capybara needs it to know the app has started up and is ready to go.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Definitely didn't plan on stubbing it, I figured it was something capybara relied on. Was more just curious what it's purpose was. Seems like it's an indicator that the app has started.

Comment: To save the next person a few minutes: `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)` will allow these local requests while still disabling remote ones.

Answer (score 1):

For VCR you can configure this way:

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  // more VCR configs here

  config.ignore_request do |request|
    URI(request.uri).host == "127.0.0.1"
  end
end
```